# Atom will not let me change focus from the application itself nor from the original editor tab

Tags: atom-editor

I am not sure what started it, but now suddenly when trying to use Atom (on Ubuntu Linux), it opens fine, but keeps focus on the upper-left text of the open tab. For instance, if I try to click somewhere else in the file to move, the cursor, the cursor jumps back to the beginning of the file. If I click on another tab to look at a different file, it immediately jumps back to the original tab, upper left corner of the text. If I hit ctrl-f to search for something, focus jumps back to the text editor. If I try to switch to a different application like Chrome or the terminal window, Atom immediately comes back into focus.

Has anyone else run into this behavior or maybe knows what's going on?

I tried purging and re-installing but am still running into the same behavior.

Comment: What (if any) non-standard packages do you have installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the behavior presents itself any time I try to edit a .ts file, at which point it automatically opens a file "child.js" in the TypeScript plugin directory and begins to display this behavior. I updated the TypeScript plugin and that seemed to fix it. Maybe this can be of help to anyone else who runs into the issue. (Bug link: https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/1098)